# How can I use a Variable as input to a javascript Widget?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, containers

I want to use the variable "sym" instead of hardcoding the actual symbol to 
load the page - for example because I want to prompt for input of the symbol.
(I trimmed other input to the widget to bare minimum to highlight the key line.)

Instead of the ' "Name", "MSFT" ' line should be the proper construction using sym.
I spent dozens of hours trying different ways and encounter identical problems 
often enough that I would really appreciate your help to get this solved.

The snippet does not seem to run here, but pasting it for example into https://codepen.io/pen/ or http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ or local html file runs just fine in hardcoded form.

```html
<script> var sym = "MSFT" </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.MediumWidget(
  {
  "container_id": "tv-medium-widget",
  "symbols": [ [
      "Name", "MSFT"
<!--  "Name",  sym     in proper formating is what I need -->
             ] ],
  "width": "1000",
  "locale": "en"
  }
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me as it stands--all I did is uncomment your array element and clean up the code a bit:

```
<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>

<script>

  var sym = "MSFT";

  new TradingView.MediumWidget({
    "container_id": "tv-medium-widget",
    "symbols": [
      [
        "Name", sym
      ]
    ],
    "width": "1000",
    "locale": "en"
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Amazing, it sure works!  Thank you!  I must have tried umpteen fancy permutations with elements and quotes/no quotes, etc.  I finally gave up and submitted my post formatted in the snippet just as on top, thinking I just put something symbolical to illustrate my problem.